# Resume or CV/curriculum-vitae

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Depending on where you are from in the world, you call the tool you use to promote yourself to potential contractors/employers a "Resume" (also "Résumé" or "Resumé"), or a "Curriculum Vitae" (also CV, *lit. "Way of Life", latin*).

Which of these should be the primary target for a tag synonym; which should be the main tag out of the two, where the other is auto-corrected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever local variations exist in word usage or spelling, we often say the author should use whatever they are most comfortable with in their post. But when it comes to variations in spelling within tags, we opted to standardize on the American version, simply as a matter of uniform convention.

So if there's a choice to be made, I'd say use "resume" as the main tag and alias "cv" as a synonym, making them functionally equivalent.

Comment: I assumed as much, but I wanted to make sure first

Comment: So French over Latin? I've noted that both are misspelled BTW ;)